# Hide UI element (C/C++ category) via eclipse activities

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to hide UI-elements via the eclipse activities. I implemented the activities successfully for the following issues:

- menu item
- context menu item
- toolbar icon

Unfortunately I don't make it for the project wizards of the category C/C++ ("Data -> New -> Other..." what you can actually see in the attachment)

I tried the following pattern, 
`<activityPatternBinding    activityId="random" pattern="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.*"/>`
with success, but this pattern hides a lot of other things too. So I tried to hide the  `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wizards.*`, but that didn't work, probably the wrong pattern plugin id.

So am I on the right way to hide the `C/C++` category with the `activityPatternBinding` or should I use the `categoryActivityBinding`? But therefore I need a valid `categoryId`. I tried the plugin-spy, I searched inside the jar files, I googled it, but I don't find the right pattern to hide the `C/C++` category in the project builder.

Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally the following pattern solved my problem:

pattern="org.eclipse.cdt.ui/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wizards.*"